Words are chameleons, which reflect
"Words are chameleons, which reflect the color of their environment."---Learned Hand.
In the above quote, what does "which" refer back to? "Words" or "chameleons"?

It doesn't make any difference, since "words" and "chameleons" have just been equated anyway! But with similar sentences where it could make a difference, by default, which refers back to the nearest preceding noun. Unless that doesn't make sense, which means you go back further looking for a suitable candidate. So in my preceding sentence, obviously which can't refer back to sense (in fact, that one refers back to the entire assertion that doesn't make sense). As usual, context is what makes the difference, not syntax.

...if someone claimed which referred to chameleons, I could only interpret it as meaning that some chameleons don't reflect surrounding colours. But words aren't like them; words are only similar to those chameleons that do change colour. Not a very likely thing for anyone to say.

It refers to chameleons is what words are.

Clearly 'which' refers to chameleons, since they change their physical colour but words do not. It's not an equality, but a simile. Words have an emotional effect in the mind of the reader, which might be called their 'colour'. That depends on the reader and the context, but the word itself has not changed.
If words change their colour to suit the surroundings, it's a metaphor. Words are not chameleons, but might be considered to have a similar nature.
